# Arrange array so adjacent has less space that gives minimum sum

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array of numbers with even size, here is my task:

a) Discard any 2 elements from the array.
b) Then pair the elements and calculate the sum of differences between the elements in the pair such that the sum is minimum.

**Example:**

```
array size even say 8.
array elements : 1,3,4,6,3,4,100,200

Ans:
5
```

**Explanation:**

> Here I will remove 100 and 200, as pairing them gives me a difference of (200 - 100) = 100.
> So remaining elements are [1,3,4,6,3,4]
> Pairs with minimum sum are : (1 3) , (4 3), (6 4).
> = |3-1| = 2, |4-3|=1,|6-4| = 2. So Sum = 2 + 1 + 2 = 5

**Example:**

```
array size even say 4.
array elements : 1,50,51,60

Ans:
1
```

**Explanation**: Here I will remove 1 and 60 so I will get the minimum sum.
So the remaining elements are [50, 51], same as the adjacent   [50 51] = 1. My code will fail for this case and returns 49.

How to achieve this in java?

I tried sorting the elements like this but this is not the correct approach for all kinds of inputs.

```
public static int process(int[] a) {
   int n = a.length;
   int n1 = n/2-1;
   Arrays.sort(arr);
   int sum = 0;
   for(int i=0; i<n1*2; i+=2) {
     sum += a[i+1] - a[i];
   }
   return sum;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide example(s) of inputs that this doesn't work for?  And how are you deciding which pair to remove?

Comment: @Scott Hunter, I have provided them, array elements : 1,50,51,60. For this input it fails. I have to find the minimum sum as result so based on that I will remove any 2 elements.

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to even try to remove 2 elements; if I'm missing it, could you point out where it does this?

Comment: @ScottHunter, This part of code does it `int n1 = n/2-1;` and then `i<n1*2`.

Comment: Sorting the array is the first step.  Next, calculate the difference between adjacent numbers.  Find the largest difference and remove the number.  Repeat finding the largest difference and removing the number.  Finally, calculate the sum of the remaining differences.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: What "number" would your "algorithm" first remove from 1,2,100,200,400,401, and why?  What about 1,2,100,300,400,401?

Comment: @Scott Hunter: I should know better than to comment on algorithm questions.  I have no idea what the correct algorithm is.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: That doesn't sound *at all* like the "algorithm" you posted.  And it is wrong: in both cases, the smallest sum is achieved by leaving 1,2,400,401 (for a sum of 2).

Comment: @learner I found a simple algorithm. However, I can only provide a C++ code, not a java one. Are you interested anyway by a presentation of the algorithm?

Comment: @Damien, please share, I will try to understand the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this kind of problem, the real issue is to find a good algorithm.
this post will insists on this aspect. A C++ code is provided at the end just to illustrate it.

It is clear we must begin by sorting the array.
A solution consists in iteratively calculate three sums, where

```
sum0 is the minimum sum assuming no element has been removed
sum1 is the minimum sum assuming one element has been removed
sum2 is the minimum sum assuming two elements has been removed
```

During this process, the code must keep trace of the last element available to calculate a difference,
one for each sum (`i_dispo0, i_dispo1, i_dispo2`).

Principles:

```
- if sum1 > sum0: sum1 is replaced by sum0
- if sum2 > sum1: sum2 is replaced by sum1
```

**Complexity:** `O(n logn)`for sorting, `O(n)` for the optimization phase.

**Code:**

The algorithm is illustrated by the following simple code in C++.
It should be easy to understand.

*Output:*
5
1
2
0
2

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int min_sum_diff (std::vector<int>& arr) {
    int n = arr.size();
    if (n%2) exit (1);
    std::sort (arr.begin(), arr.end());
    int sum0 = 0, sum1 = arr[n-1] - arr[0] + 1, sum2 = arr[n-1] - arr[0] + 1;
    int i_dispo0 = -1, i_dispo1 = -1, i_dispo2 = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int sum0_old = sum0;
        int sum1_old = sum1;
        if (i_dispo0 == -1) {
            i_dispo0 = i;
        } else {
            sum0 += arr[i] - arr[i_dispo0];
            i_dispo0 = -1;
        }
        if (i_dispo1 == -1) {
            i_dispo1 = i;
        } else {
            int add = arr[i] - arr[i_dispo1];
            if (sum0_old < sum1 + add) {
                sum1 = sum0_old;
                i_dispo1 = i;
            } else {
                sum1 += add;
                i_dispo1 = -1;
            }
        }
        if (i_dispo2 == -1) {
            i_dispo2 = i;
        } else {
            sum2 += arr[i] - arr[i_dispo2];
            i_dispo2 = -1;
        }
        
        if (sum2 > sum1_old) {
            sum2 = sum1_old;
            i_dispo2 = i;
        }
        //std::cout << i << " : " << sum0 << "  " << sum1 << "  " << sum2 << '\n';
    }
    return sum2;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> examples = {
        {1, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4, 100, 200},   // -> 5
        {1, 50, 51, 60},                // -> 1
        {1,2,100,200,400,401},          // -> 2
        {1, 10, 10, 20, 30, 30},        // -> 0
        {1, 10, 11, 20, 30, 31}         // -> 2
    };
    for (std::vector<int>& arr: examples) {
        int sum = min_sum_diff (arr);
        std::cout << sum << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Someone just downvoted this answer. If there is any mistake in it, I would like to know such that to be able to correct it.

Comment: Looks good to me. *shrug*

Answer (score 2):

## Simple block code *for understanding*

[image]

---

## Java Code

```java
package com.company;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        System.out.println(MinSumDiff(new int[] {1,2,3,4,4,6,100,200}));
    }

    private static int MinSumDiff(int[] arr) {
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        int n = arr.length;
        if(!(0==(n%2))){
            System.exit(2);// '2' refers not divisible by 2
        }
        int sum0 = 0,
            sum1 = arr[n-1] - arr[0] + 1,//LAST ITEM OF ARRAY(LARGEST) - FIRST(SMALLEST) ITEM
            sum2 = sum1;
        int dispo0 = -1,
            dispo1 = -1,
            dispo2 = -1;

        for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
            int sum0_old = sum0;//SET OLD TO CURRENT BECAUSE CURRENT(SUM0) WILL CHANGE LATER, WE CAN USE THIS FOR VERIFICATION
            int sum1_old = sum1;//SET OLD TO CURRENT BECAUSE CURRENT(SUM1) WILL CHANGE LATER, WE CAN USE THIS FOR VERIFICATION
            //------------------------------------------------------------
            if (dispo0 == -1) {
                dispo0 = i;//SET CURENT `I` FOR USE FOR NEXT TIME'S PREVIOUS ...[1]
            } else {
                sum0 += arr[i] - arr[dispo0];//CURRENT ITEM - PREVIOUS ITEM(PREVIOUS FROM [1])
                dispo0 = -1;//REPEAT 
            }
            //------------------------------------------------------------
            if (dispo1 == -1) {
                dispo1 = i;//SET CURENT `I` FOR USE FOR NEXT TIME'S PREVIOUS ...[2]
            } else {
                int add = arr[i] - arr[dispo1];//CURRENT ITEM - PREVIOUS ITEM(PREVIOUS FROM [2])
                if (sum0_old < sum1 + add) {
                    sum1 = sum0_old;//IF `SUM0(OLD)` IS LESS THAN `SUM1` THEN WHY DO YOU AVOID IT,SO SET `SUM1` TO `SUM0(OLD)`
                    dispo1 = i;//SETS `I` NOT AS -1 BECAUSE IT WANTS TO DO THIS AGAIN AND CHECK
                } else {
                    sum1 += add;//IF ADDING THE VARIABLE `ADD` WILL BE LESS THAN SUM0(OLD) THEN YOU CAN ADD IT TO `SUM1` NOW
                    dispo1 = -1;//REPEAT 
                }
            }
            //------------------------------------------------------------
            if (dispo2 == -1) {
                dispo2 = i;//SET CURENT `I` FOR USE FOR NEXT TIME'S PREVIOUS ...[3]
            } else {
                sum2 += arr[i] - arr[dispo2];//CURRENT ITEM - PREVIOUS ITEM(PREVIOUS FROM [3]) ...4
                dispo2 = -1;//REPEAT 
            }
            //------------------------------------------------------------
            if (sum2 > sum1_old) {
                sum2 = sum1_old;//IF `SUM1(OLD)` IS LESS THAN `SUM2` THEN WHY DO YOU AVOID IT,SO SET `SUM2` TO `SUM1(OLD)`
                dispo2 = i;//EVEN THOUGH `DISPO2` IS -1 IT SETS TO `I` BECAUSE OF ABOVE CODE EXECUTION (WHICH IS USEFUL FOR [4])
            }
            //------------------------------------------------------------
        }
        return sum2;//RETURN THE FINAL RESULT THAT'S STORED IN LAST VARIABLE SUM2!!!
    }
}
```

---

---

P.S

> The idea is from [@danien's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10553341/damien) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70622902/14862885)

> I have convert it to block code&java code with ***explained comments***

Answer (score 1):

I tested the previous posted solution for various other inputs but it was not valid for different sets of inputs. Hence , I am posting a different approach that is working fine for different sets of inputs.

#### Approach:-

- Sort the array in ascending order
- Take a variable to initialize the `minimum sum` to the `sum of difference of the last two and first two elements` of the array.
- Start a `loop` (with initially `excluding the last two elements of array`).
- Each run of loop should `calculate the sum of difference of pairs` and `compare it with minimum sum` to update its value if the current run of loop has the minimum total.
- Hence , we will be covering all the pairs after we finish with the execution of loop and will get the minimum sum .

  ```java
      public static int findMinSum(int[] a){
              Arrays.sort(a);
              int minSum=a[1]-a[0]+a[a.length-1]-a[a.length-2];
              for (int i=0,j=a.length-2;i<a.length/2 && j<a.length;i++,j++){
                  int sum=0;
                  int counter=i;
                  while(counter<j){
                      sum=sum+(a[counter+1]-a[counter]);
                      counter+=2;
                  }
                  if(sum < minSum){
                      minSum=sum;
                  }
              }
              return minSum;
          }
  ```

#### Example:-

```
- original array={95,98,100,101,102,110}
- initialize minimum sum to (110-102)+(98-95) = 11
- loop stages : 
     - (98-95) +(101-100) = 4 (new minimum sum=4)
     - (100-98)+(102-101) = 3 (new minimum sum=3)
     - (101-100)+(110-102) = 9 (minimum sum remains 3)
```

I have further tested the following set of inputs :-

```
{1,3,3,4,4,6,100,200}
{1,50,51,60}
{1,2,100,200,400,401}
{1,2,100,300,400,401}
{1,2,3,4,4,6,100,200}
{95,98,100,101,102,401}
```

Please do inform if any descrepancies occur for any input sets.

Comment: OK, it happens to work on the example because of the zeros, but it returns `5` for `1,2,3,4,4,6,100,200`, when the correct answer is `4`.

Comment: -David Eisenstat Thanks for pointing out . Made the required modification in the code .

Answer (score 0):

The OP states that in the first step any two elements can be removed from the array. If that is the case, thereafter the problem is equal to finding a maximum weighted matching in a graph. See e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_weight_matching) explanation.

Implementations for algorithms for this problem can be found [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/graph/doc/maximum_weighted_matching.html) (with a good explanation of the problem itself) in Boost (C++). In Java, which the OP is after, several algorithms can be found [here](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org.jgrapht.core/org/jgrapht/alg/matching/package-summary.html), in the [JGraphT](https://jgrapht.org/) library.

Note that usually the algorithms are written for a maximum weight, whereas the OP is after a minimum weight. The strategy to cast the graph in this form is to:

- Create a graph where each element of the array is a vertex
- Each edge (connection between each vertex) has a weight equal to the absolute difference between the value of both vertices, multiplied by -1

To illustrate, in the original example, after removal of 100 and 200, the following elements remain in the array: 1,3,4,6,3,4. Each element represents an edge (say A, B, C, D, E, F). The vertex A-B has weight -2, the vertex A-C has weight -3, and so on. If we apply an algorithm to find a maximum matching with maximum weight in this graph, it will correspond to a minimum weight in the OP's problem.